# I am trying to apply animation inside MODAL content but doesn't work (aos animation)

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, modal-dialog

```js
AOS.init({
  duration: 1800,
  delay: 300,
})

$(function() {
  //----- OPEN
  $('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e) {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(550);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  //----- CLOSE
  $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e) {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(550);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $(".popup").click(function() {
    $(".popup").fadeOut(550).removeClass("active");
  });
  $(".popup-inner").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
<style>#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background: url(Mimg/tree.png) absolute;
  background: url(Mimg/testback2.png) no-repeat center absolute;
}

a1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a2 {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.fishes {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.fish {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
}

.fish:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.5;
}


/* Outer */

.popup {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}


/* Inner */

.popup-inner {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
}


/* Close Button */

.popup-close {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  transition: ease 0.25s all;
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 1000px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.popup-close:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="plugin/aos/aos.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <img class="fishes" src="Mimg/testback2.png">
  <a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#"><img class="fish" src="Mimg/tree.png" data-aos="zoom-in"></a>
  <div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
      <a1 data-aos="zoom-in">Wow! This is Awesome! (Popup #1)</a1><br>
      <img data-aos="zoom-in" width="100%" class="run" src="Mimg/run-1.gif"><br>
      <a2 data-aos="zoom-in">Donec in volutpat nisi. In quam lectus, aliquet rhoncus cursus a, congue et arcu. Vestibulum tincidunt neque id nisi pulvinar aliquam. Nulla luctus luctus ipsum at ultricies. Nullam nec velit dui. Nullam sem eros, pulvinar sed pellentesque ac, feugiat
        et turpis. Donec gravida ipsum cursus massa malesuada tincidunt. Nullam finibus nunc mauris, quis semper neque ultrices in. Ut ac risus eget eros imperdiet posuere nec eu lectus.</a2>
      <p>
        <a2 data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#"><u>Close</u></a2>
      </p>
      <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">X</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I put `data-aos="zoom-in"` inside the content of modal become doesn't work, but it works with the photo button.

Any idea for this?